# Setting a series of string constants in Python 3

Tags: python, attributes

There is a class in my code that handles displaying outputs. A series of colors, brushes and pens needs to be set inside this class, but I'm unsure how.

1. Should I set them as individual class attributes?

   ```
   GREEN = '#00ff00'
   BLUE = '#0000ff'
   RED = '#ff0000'
   ```
2. Should I add them to a dictionary?

   ```
   colours = {'GREEN': '#00ff00',
              'BLUE': '#0000ff',
              'RED': '#ff0000'}
   ```
3. Should I loop over them and assign all using `__setattr__` method of the instance?

   ```
   for k, v in colours.items():
       mydraw.__setattr__(k, v)
   ```

Isn't it conventional to access these attributes as `module.item`; such as `logging.WARN` or `wx.HORIZONTAL`? Also, should I set them inside a class or in the module?

Comment: The answers are really going to be a matter of opinion.  Use what you and your coworkers feel most comfortable with if there's not already a pattern in the project.

Comment: @tristan Sure, but is there a python standard for doing this? I am assuming this could effect readability.

Answer (score 1):

Per the style guide, [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants) (emphasis mine):

> Constants are **usually defined on a module level** and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include `MAX_OVERFLOW` and `TOTAL`.

There are various examples of this in the standard library, see e.g. [`logging`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/070fed5b7b9d/Lib/logging/__init__.py), [`tkinter`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/070fed5b7b9d/Lib/tkinter/constants.py) and [`re`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/070fed5b7b9d/Lib/re.py).

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.4, you can inherit from the class `enum` as follows:

```
from enum import Enum

class Colour(Enum):
    GREEN = '#00ff00'
    BLUE = '#0000ff'
    RED = '#ff0000'
```

And then simply type `Colour.GREEN.value` and so on...

Another option, that neither requires Python 3.4 nor typing `Colour.GREEN.value`:

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

Colour = enum(GREEN='#00ff00', BLUE='#0000ff', RED='#ff0000')
```

Then `Colour.GREEN` evaluates to `'#00ff00'`.

Comment: Wouldn't this require typing `colour.GREEN.value` to get their string values?